# Mcollecitve mco shell command is not working

Tags: puppet, mcollective

I am using mcollective-2.8.1 version and installed all the related packages, but its seems like shell command is missing. I am not able to find the package/plugin for shell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MCollective Shell is a separate Agent plugin, it is not packaged with the core MCollective software. Agent plugin code is installed into *$libdir/mcollective/agent*. See the [general plugin install guide](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/mcollective-plugins/wiki/InstallingPlugins). You can get the Agent code from [GitHub](https://github.com/puppetlabs/mcollective-shell-agent).

Comment: Thanks Luke, I have setup that, I forgot to update my answer here.